# Code completion not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, autosuggest

I have updated android studio and now the code completion (which was working earlier in the previous version) is not working. When the shortkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed it shows:

[image]

I have already tried Invalidating the Cache and Restarting the Android Studio, as mentioned in another post.

Can someone point what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to type `android:` for Intellij to give you options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if **Power Save Mode** on **File menu** is enabled accidentally.
2. Also check in **File > Settings > Editor > Inspections**:

   - Android
   - Android Lint
3. In **File > Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion**:

   - Autopopup code completion should be checked

Comment: Thank You Alberto, that did it!